# Kendo column filtering icon shows additional dot in IE

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, internet-explorer-11

I got this small but strange error while implementing kendo column filters. My filtering icon has an additional dot in IE. In all other browsers everything looks fine. I don't know how to delete or at least hide this small additional dot.

Here is the screenshot from IE:

[image]

and here is how it should look like:

[image]

I used a regular kendo filtering implementation, example of the code is below:

```
var MyGrid = function($div) {
   var base = $div.data('baseurl');

   var columns = [ 
   { field: 'userName', title: 'User Name'}, 
   { field: 'age', type:'number', title: 'Age' }];

   grid($div, columns, {
     datasource: datasource(base + '/double', ViewBackbone.options()),
     options: {
        filterable : {
            extra: false,
            operators: {
              string: {
                contains: "Contains",
                startswith: "Starts with",
                eq: "Equals"
              },
              number: {
                eq: "Is equal",
                gt: "Greater than",
                lt: "Less than"
              }
            },
            messages: {
                info: "Choose an option",
                filter:"Filter",
                clear: "Clear"
            }
        },      
     }
  });        
};
```

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer are you using? Does this repro with the online demos hosted on telerik.com? The dots look (if I recall correctly), like empty image elements, or images that are 0x0.

Comment: @Sampson - I am using the last version of IE: 11.20...

Comment: IE 11 on Windows 7, 8.1, or 10? Also, can you direct me to an online resource that shows the issue?

Comment: @Sampson - I am using windows 10. This dot is not representing an empty image element. It is positioned in a strange place as you can see in the picture example above. Comparing with some old project, I noticed that the dot is presented not just with a filter image, but also with any other element attached to a column header(dropdown menu, filter, etc..). I can't point you to an online resource because it is a private project for my client.

Comment: Can you put together a minimal repro? Just a small sample, consisting of as little code a possible, that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Sampson - I added a piece of code, it's just a regular and simple usage of kendo grids with filters added.

Comment: Can you place a functioning demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by fixing the width property to the columns header. So in your css you have to specify the width to be more than 100%. I set up mine to be 115% and the dot disapeered.